# Returning a list with the smallest number of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I made a list of lists of submatrices, given a random matrix:

```r
mat <- matrix(1:30, ncol = 5)
mat

n <- nrow(mat)
m <- ncol(mat)
r <- seq_len(min(n, m))

r.combs <- structure(choose(n, r)*choose(m, r), names = r) 
print(r.combs)

sum(r.combs)

res <- structure(vector("list", length(r)), names = paste0("r", r))

for (R in r) {
  tmp <- list()
  R_n <- combn(n, R, simplify = FALSE) 
  R_m <- combn(m, R, simplify = FALSE)
  for(i in seq_along(R_n)) {
    for (j in seq_along(R_m)){
      tmp <- c(tmp, list(mat[R_n[[i]], R_m[[j]], drop = FALSE]))
    }
  }
  res[[R]] <- tmp
}

res
```

As of now, it returns the whole list which includes lists of matrices. I am trying to make it so that my code returns ONLY the list with the least amount of matrices, in this case res$r5, but without having to manually write res$r5 so that it can work with different sizes in which case the smallest might be a different r value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide us what you have tried so far so that we can provide further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `lengths` of your list and determine the minimum. Use the result to subset your list

```
res[which.min(lengths(res))]
#$r5
#$r5[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    7   13   19   25
#[2,]    2    8   14   20   26
#[3,]    3    9   15   21   27
#[4,]    4   10   16   22   28
#[5,]    5   11   17   23   29
#
# ...
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!